# Accuracy 100% with grid search? What is wrong?

Tags: logistic-regression, evaluation

When I run Logistic Regression with default parameters accuracy = 98%
After grid search accuracy = 100%. Is it possible? Could this happen because of bad dataset? here is my code so far.

````
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, stratify=y, random_state=42)

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

sfk = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, random_state=21, shuffle=True)

lr = LogisticRegression()
lr_param_grid = {
    'C': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000],
    'penalty': ['l1', 'l2'],
    'max_iter': list(range(100,800,100)),
    'solver': ['newton-cg', 'lbfgs', 'liblinear', 'sag', 'saga']}

lr_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=lr, param_grid=lr_param_grid,cv=sfk)
lr_search.fit(X_train, y_train)

lr_test_predicitons = lr_search.predict(X_test)
print(metrics.classification_report(y_test, lr_test_predicitons))
print('Mean Accuracy (test set): %.3f' % accuracy_score(y_test,lr_test_predicitons))```

  precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       1.00      1.00      1.00       155
           1       1.00      1.00      1.00        57

    accuracy                           1.00       212
   macro avg       1.00      1.00      1.00       212
weighted avg       1.00      1.00      1.00       212
````

Answer (score 0):

Grid Search Alghoritm finds the parameters to obtain the best accuracy. Morover it has the default parameter euqals True, so it can happen and if the dataset it very small it is very likely

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).